# unable to retrieve value from Get request [Nancy]

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli, nancy

i'm trying to create a local server, so that winform can be controlled via web request [Get Request]
i'm using [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) to create a local server. i've written winform using C++/Cli. but handling GET Request in C# class
i can result in web browser when i hit ip address http://localhost:12345/something but unable to retrieve data into some variable

below is my C# code

```
using System;
using Nancy;

namespace WebService
{
    public class NancyClass : NancyModule
    {
        public delegate void pushData(Nancy.DynamicDictionaryValue value);
        public pushData pd;

        public NancyClass()
        {
            Get["/{t}"] = parameters => 
            {
                try
                {
                    pd(parameters.t); //Null Exception here
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex); 
                }
                return "Result is " + parameters.t;
            };
        }        
    }  
}
```

above code generates following error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an obj ect.    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , pushData ,
>   Object )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite
>   site,  T0 arg0, T1 arg1)    at
>   WebService.NancyClass.<.ctor>b__2_0(Object parameters) in
>   G:\Sample\project\NancyClass.cs:line 16

below code belongs to C++/Cli winform

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{            
    using namespace System;
    using namespace Nancy::Hosting::Self;
    using namespace Nancy;

    public:MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebService::NancyClass ^nc = gcnew WebService::NancyClass();
        nc->pd = gcnew WebService::NancyClass::pushData(this, &MyForm::Data_from_webServer);            
        auto host = gcnew NancyHost(gcnew Uri("http://localhost:12345"));
        host->Start(); // start hosting
     }
 };
```

i cannot even print `parameters.t` in C# class
`Console.WriteLine(parameters.t)` or `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(parameters.t))` leads to following error

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The call is
>   ambiguous bet ween the following methods or properties:
>   'System.Console.WriteLine(string, para ms object[])' and
>   'System.Console.WriteLine(bool)'    at CallSite.Target(Closure ,
>   CallSite , Type , Object )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite
>   site,  T0 arg0, T1 arg1)    at
>   WebService.NancyClass.<.ctor>b__2_0(Object parameters) in
>   G:\Sample\project\NancyClass.cs:line 16

Comment: Did you ever set `pd`?

Comment: @BenVoigt, i used C++/Cli syntax .. what changes do i need to make?   in C++ class i'm linking `pd` to a function like this `nc->pd = gcnew WebService::NancyClass::pushData(this, &MyForm::Data_from_webServer);`